# ¿Cómo evitar que Fullcalendar muestre días que no son del mes actual?

Tags: php, html, fullcalendar

¿quién me puede ayudar?, estoy utilizando fullcalendar pero tengo un problema, y es que me muestra unos días del mes anterior y unos días del mes siguiente... ¿cómo puedo hacer para que solo me muestre los días del mes actual?

Gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La documentacion dice que para deshabilitar esos dias tenes que poner el atributo `showNonCurrentDates` en `false`

> https://fullcalendar.io/docs/showNonCurrentDates